# Getting started with React Native, making http requests

Tags: react-native

Ok, so i just started out with React Native and googled the subject I was able to make this:

index.ios.js:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var { AppRegistry } = React;
var MarvelsApp = require('./components/start');

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MarvelsApp', () => MarvelsApp);
```

start.js:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    TextInput,
    StatusBar,
    ListView
} = React;

 var b = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=XXXXXX';
 console.log('api url',b);

var stylesStart = React.StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            backgroundColor: 'pink',
            flex: 1
        },
        test: {
            color: 'black',
            fontSize: 22
        }
});

var Start = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
              movie: [],
    };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
    fetchData: function(){
        fetch(b)
            .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                        console.log('Logging api response', data.results);
                        this.setState({
                            movie: data
                        });
                })
                .done();
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={stylesStart.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
                <Text style={stylesStart.test}>{this.state.movie.title}</Text>
            </View>

        );
    }
});

module.exports = Start;
```

[image]

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to make an http request using the api from themoviedb.org. And then to display the retrieved data in the view.

So far I am able to pull in the data via the http request but I am not having much luck showing it in the view. Now this could be because I missed a step or because I am doing it wrong.

Please point out to me where or what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the wrong key from this.state, try logging this.state and see the structure of it. You'll probably need to call this.state.movie[0].title to see the title.

Answer (score 0):

you init the state variable movie as an array
 (`return {movie: [],};`),

but you use it as an object (`this.state.movie.title`),

finally, you update the state (`this.setState({movie: data});`)

make sure the type you use are you need.

if you want to render as a list , the state variable movie should be an array, or you just want to render a item ,it could be an object